# drawToolbar is undefined

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I keep receiving the error "drawToolbar is undefined" when I click a button to enable the Draw Toolbar from the ArcGIS JavaScript API.  I also have the navTool bar in the map so as I understand I need to make sure that only one toolbar is active at a time.

My HTML and JavaScript code are in separate files so I will split them up below.

HTML (excerpt):

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="clickforXY" iconClass="clickforXY" onClick="drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);">Click for XY</div>
```

Javascript:
dojo.require("esri.map");
//dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend");
//dojo.require("esri.dijit.OverviewMap");
dojo.require("esri.toolbars.navigation");
dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
dojo.require("esri.dijit.BasemapGallery");
//dojo.require("esri.virtualearth.VETiledLayer");
dojo.require("esri.toolbars.draw");

```
    setConfigProperties();
    
    var map, navToolbar, symbol, geomtask, visible = [];
    var drawToolbar;
    var gsvc = null;
      var pt = null;
      
      function init(){
        var layersLoaded = 0;  //variable to keep track of when all layers have been loaded.
        var loading = dojo.byId("loadingImg");  //loading image. id
        var initialExtent = startExtent;  //Extent values are in config.js.
        map = new esri.Map("map", {
            extent: initialExtent, logo:false
        });
        
        gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://dal-gisweb/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
        
        dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", showLoading);
        dojo.connect(map, "onZoomStart", showLoading);
        dojo.connect(map, "onPanStart", showLoading);
        dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(map){
            dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', resizeMap);
        dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", createdrawToolbar);
        //dojo.connect(map, "onClick", projectToLatLong);
        });
        
        function showLoading() {
          esri.show(loading);
          //map.disableMapNavigation();
          //map.hideZoomSlider();
        }

        function hideLoading(error){
            layersLoaded++;
            if (layersLoaded === map.layerIds.length) {
                esri.hide(loading);
                //map.enableMapNavigation();
                //map.showZoomSlider();
                layersLoaded = 0;
            }
        }
        
        //Set up the TOC for initial map load.
        //Use the ImageParameters to set the visible layers in the map service during ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer construction.
        var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
        imageParameters.layerIds = initialLayers;
        imageParameters.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
        //can also be: LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE, LAYER_OPTION_HIDE, LAYER_OPTION_INCLUDE
        
        //The path to the services are located in the config.js.
        basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(basemapservice);
        //oppllayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(opplservice);
        dynamicLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(dynamicservice, {"imageParameters":imageParameters});
        
        dojo.connect(map, 'onLayersAddResult', function(results){
            //add the legend 
                    var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: [{
                            layer: dynamicLayer,
                            title: "Crosstex"
                        }],
                        arrangement: esri.dijit.Legend.ALIGN_Left
                    }, "legendDiv");
                    legend.startup();
                });
                dynamicLayer.setOpacity(0.8);
                map.addLayer(basemap);
                dojo.connect(basemap, "onUpdateEnd", hideLoading);
                map.addLayer(dynamicLayer);
                dojo.connect(dynamicLayer, "onUpdateEnd", hideLoading);
                
                  
                //Add the ArcGIS BaseMap Gallery.
                createBasemapGallery();
                dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', resizeMap);
                
                                
                function resizeMap(){
                    //resize the map when the browser resizes - view the 'Resizing and repositioning the map' section in
                    //the following help topic for more details http://help.esri.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_guidelines.htm
                    var resizeTimer;
                    dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(theMap){
                        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', function(){ //resize the map if the div is resized
                            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
                            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                                map.resize();
                                map.reposition();
                            }, 500);
                        });
                    });
                }
                navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
                dojo.connect(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);
                
                //set position of the zoom slider at X pixels offset from left/bottom of map
                esriConfig.defaults.map.slider = { left:"10px", top:"35px", width:null, height:"200px" };
            }
            
        function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {
        dijit.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
        dijit.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
      }
//Sets up the ability for dynamic layers to be toggled.
        function updatedynamicLayerVisibility(){
            var inputs = dojo.query(".list_item"), input;
            //Placing layer numbers below will enforce them to be visible.
            visible = [];
            for (var i = 0, il = inputs.length; i < il; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].checked) {
                    visible.push(inputs[i].id);
                }
            }
            dynamicLayer.setVisibleLayers(visible);
            
        }
//Sets up the ability for OPPL layers to be toggled.
        function updateOPPLLayerVisibility(){
            var inputs = dojo.query(".list_item"), input;
            //Placing layer numbers below will enforce them to be visible.
            visible = [];
            for (var i = 0, il = inputs.length; i < il; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].checked) {
                    visible.push(inputs[i].id);
                }
            }
            oppllayer.setVisibleLayers(visible);
            
        }

    function createBasemapGallery() {

         var basemapGallery = new esri.dijit.BasemapGallery({
          showArcGISBasemaps: true,
          map: map
        }, "basemapGallery");

        basemapGallery.startup();
        
        dojo.connect(basemapGallery, "onError", function(msg) {console.log(msg)});
      }
//Sets up the funcions for the GoToXY
    function createPoint(){
        map.graphics.clear(pnt_xysym);
        var infoSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_X, 15, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([0,255,0,1]));
       
               
       //add point using the coordinates fromt he form below.
       var pnt_X = document.getElementById("frm_X").value;
       var pnt_Y = document.getElementById("frm_Y").value;
       var pnt_xy = new esri.geometry.Point(pnt_X, pnt_Y, map.spatialReference);
       
       var pnt_xysym = new esri.Graphic(esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(pnt_xy), infoSymbol);
       
       map.graphics.add(pnt_xysym);
       map.centerAndZoom(esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(pnt_xy), map.getLevel()+1); 
      
      }
      //Create the drawing toolbar.
      function createdrawToolbar(map) {
        
        drawToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
        //drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
        dojo.connect(drawToolbar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);
        
      }
      
      function addToMap(geometry) {
      map.graphics.clear();
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      map.showZoomSlider();
       switch (geometry.type) {
          case "point":
            var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_X, 10, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([0,255,0,1]));
            
        }
        
        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
        projectToLatLong(geometry);
      }
      
      function projectToLatLong(evt) {
        //map.graphics.clear();
        var point = evt;
        var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326});
        
 
        gsvc.project([ point ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {
          
         pt = projectedPoints[0];
          //display list of points in extent
          dojo.byId("results").innerHTML = "&nbsp;Lat: " + pt.y.toFixed(6) + ",&nbsp;Long: " + pt.x.toFixed(6);
          
        });
      }
      //Used to deactivate tools in order to enable others.
      function deactAllTools() {
       navToolbar.deactivate();
       drawToolbar.deactivate();
        }

      //show map on load 
      dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

To view this in action you can follow the link below.
http://geoville.org/viewers/samplesviewer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code looks wrong to me:

```
dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(map){
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', resizeMap);
  dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", createdrawToolbar);
  //dojo.connect(map, "onClick", projectToLatLong);
});
```

Looks like you are trying to connect to the 'onLoad' event from the onLoad event, which I'm guessing is causing createdrawToolbar to never be called.  Try this:

```
dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(map){
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', resizeMap);
  //dojo.connect(map, "onClick", projectToLatLong);
});
dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", createdrawToolbar);
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head if you can connect multiple event listeners in dojo, I think you can.  If not, you can call createdrawToolbar() directly from your first onLoad handler.

Comment: That was it!  I never caught that.  Sometimes a new set of eyes can really help.